# Postgres & docker os disk cache

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using `docker-compose` to run my database container that has fairly small memory limit (using `mem_limit` setting).

Will the docker host disk cache be used (no mem limit) by the postgres container, or should I make sure the container has enough free memory for disk caching?

*Using Debian 4.9.246-2 linux host*

Comment: This is not a dba question.  The answer would presumably be the same whether you had a bitcoin miner or Duke Nukem running inside the container rather than a database.

Comment: @jjanes the answer is the same, but my use case is running a database. I think this info should be valuable for a db admin managing a docker db instance.

Comment: Sure, and maybe you will get lucky here, but I think you are more likely to find the correct info from a docker expert than a database expert.